# R dplyr How to trim a data set based on cell values?

Tags: r, select, filter, dplyr

Using dplyr, I am trying to use "rep number 15", to identify the "set id" and keep every rep in with same "set id". My goal is to eventually run some summary statistics on the individual "set id's", but I need to eliminate the extra data first.

Edit: using dplyr, I would like to use the value 15 in the "Rep Number" column to identify the corresponding value in the "set id" column. This value is assigned to the preceding 14 rows, of which I would like to keep all of the corresponding information. There are additional "sets id's" (rows 16-24) that don't correspond with a "rep number" of 15. This is just a subset of data, so it's simple to provide an example, but the full set has many more rows of unneeded data.

I understand the basic codes for identifying values such as `x <- rpdc$`set id `[rpdc$`Rep Number `== 15]` and `y <- which(rpdc$`Rep Number `== 15)`, but can't seem to utilize that to trim down my dataframe.

My sample data is as follows

```
 dput(rpdc)
structure(list(exercise = c("Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", 
"Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", 
"Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", 
"Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", 
"Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", 
"Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", 
"Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", 
"Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", 
"Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", 
"Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", 
"Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", 
"Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press", 
"Bench Press", "Bench Press", "Bench Press"), `set id` = c(-2688, 
-2688, -2688, -2688, -2688, -2688, -2688, -2688, -2688, -2688, 
-2688, -2688, -2688, -2688, -2688, -2686, -2686, -2686, -2684, 
-2684, -2684, -2683, -2683, -2683, -2682, -2682, -2682, -2682, 
-2682, -2682, -2682, -2682, -2682, -2682, -2682, -2682, -2682, 
-2682, -2682, -2674, -2674, -2674, -2674, -2674, -2674, -2674, 
-2674, -2674, -2674, -2674, -2674, -2674, -2674, -2674), `bar weight (KG)` = c(10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 35, 35, 
35, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 
65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 
65, 65, 65, 65, 65), `Rep Number` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), `Vertical Distance(")` = c(27.768, 
31.434, 29.654, 29.089, 30.183, 30.252, 28.825, 29.636, 28.161, 
27.808, 29.839, 30.077, 30.536, 32.136, 26.933, 26.72, 27.755, 
29.33, 27.563, 28.342, 27.366, 28.071, 28.11, 29.083, 19.411, 
20.489, 19.597, 19.438, 19.157, 19.733, 18.953, 18.883, 19.348, 
18.256, 18.482, 18.894, 18.321, 19.432, 19.087, 19.337, 19.593, 
19.319, 18.635, 19.164, 18.985, 18.469, 19.514, 18.52, 18.78, 
18.666, 18.948, 19.201, 19.864, 19.248), `Concentric Time(s)` = c(0.827, 
0.934, 0.867, 0.868, 0.908, 0.911, 0.95, 0.948, 0.951, 0.908, 
1.056, 0.972, 1.245, 1.339, 0.806, 0.969, 1.03, 1.171, 0.909, 
0.91, 0.989, 0.847, 0.805, 0.826, 0.563, 0.585, 0.585, 0.626, 
0.606, 0.686, 0.646, 0.625, 0.685, 0.726, 0.726, 0.807, 0.828, 
0.849, 0.868, 0.543, 0.565, 0.563, 0.565, 0.585, 0.585, 0.646, 
0.624, 0.646, 0.666, 0.665, 0.706, 0.727, 0.768, 0.788), `Mean Force(N)` = c(934.493, 
929.081, 930.822, 929.073, 932.432, 926.381, 932.145, 928.64, 
923.847, 933.126, 926.17, 941.675, 931.5, 928.348, 975.2, 1180.886, 
1181.97, 1178.66, 1129.274, 1127.994, 1125.706, 1036.935, 1040.416, 
1033.517, 663.722, 676.834, 655.584, 656.418, 672.06, 653.77, 
656.407, 662.05, 657.197, 656.23, 662.913, 653.854, 648.483, 
655.211, 651.538, 658.221, 666.012, 676.698, 683.59, 662.983, 
674.509, 664.292, 665.332, 667.18, 659.45, 659.756, 653.508, 
665.657, 652.489, 648.576), `Mean Power(W)` = c(775.174, 782.296, 
790.43, 773.774, 768.733, 769.255, 703.302, 723.227, 686.334, 
708.397, 658.426, 767.898, 576.253, 560.252, 803.432, 808.339, 
789.61, 735.055, 850.053, 872.67, 776.319, 847.193, 890.844, 
897.497, 564.985, 594.033, 554.204, 507.104, 515.873, 468.272, 
475.517, 493.19, 456.333, 401.521, 410.119, 374.523, 353.282, 
367.442, 352.025, 580.428, 577.282, 569.644, 546.341, 534.244, 
532.895, 459.955, 506.744, 462.765, 453.095, 448.575, 428.095, 
426.065, 413.17, 389.76), `Mean Velocity(m/s)` = c(0.836, 0.845, 
0.853, 0.835, 0.83, 0.831, 0.759, 0.781, 0.741, 0.765, 0.711, 
0.828, 0.622, 0.605, 0.837, 0.689, 0.674, 0.627, 0.757, 0.778, 
0.692, 0.826, 0.868, 0.876, 0.851, 0.87, 0.829, 0.771, 0.787, 
0.715, 0.729, 0.75, 0.702, 0.625, 0.635, 0.584, 0.552, 0.572, 
0.549, 0.877, 0.859, 0.85, 0.819, 0.812, 0.807, 0.711, 0.777, 
0.713, 0.701, 0.697, 0.667, 0.659, 0.645, 0.609)), row.names = c(NA, 
-54L), groups = structure(list(exercise = c("Bench Press", "Bench Press", 
"Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin", "Pullups - Chin"
), `set id` = c(-2682, -2674, -2688, -2686, -2684, -2683), .rows = structure(list(
    25:39, 40:54, 1:15, 16:18, 19:21, 22:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If we need to get only the rows 1 to 15 for all 'exercise, regroup by 'exercise' (the OP data is grouped by 'exercise' and 'set id')

```
library(dplyr)
rpdc %>% 
   group_by(exercise) %>%
   filter(row_number() <= 15) -> rpdc2
```

Comment: Thank you, however that leaves me with a dataframe containing only the set id's and none of the other information.

Comment: @Cra538 Remove the `select` statement (updated)

Comment: using the code I listed above I am aiming for an output like this `rpdc2 <- rpdc[-c(16:24),]` . My apologies, I don't think my question was clear.

Comment: @Cra538 if you need to create an object use assignment either at the beginning or end

Comment: Added an edit to the question. Hopefully that clarifys things

Comment: @Cra538 I read your update.  It is confusing to me.  Do you  want to change the `set id` for 1 to 15 to some different value..  But the `set id` seems to be same for each element of 'exercise from 1 to 15 i.e. `rpdc %>% filter(exercise == 'Pullups - Chin') %>% select(`Rep Number`, `set id`)`

Comment: @Cra538 do you need `rpdc %>% group_by(exercise) %>%  filter(row_number() <= 15)`

Comment: I was able to figure it out using this function `slice(`set id` [which(`Rep Number` == 15)])`. Again, thank you for your time. I do appreciate it and apologies for the confusing question

Answer (score 0):

Trm1 <- rpdc %>% filter(`Rep Number` == 15)

(where 'Trm1' is your trimmed data frame, if you want to save it separately you can export using 'write.csv' function)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. That isn't quite what I need. Added an edit to my question, hopefully it clarifys my issue.